# equivalent to INSERT INTO TABLE SET in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, insert-update

I want to add data to table STATISTICS using INSERT statements.

I also want to move new counts to old counts and new date to old date as the new data comes in.

This is where it gets lil tricky because I don't know if there is such a thing as INSERT INTO table with SET in Oracle.

```
INSERT INTO STATISTICS
SET 
    MODEL = '&MY_MODEL',
    NEW_COUNT = 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM TABLE CLIENTS
    ),
    NEW_DATE = SYSDATE,
    OLD_COUNT = NEW_COUNT,
    OLD_DATE = NEW_DATE,
    PRNCT_CHANGE =  ((NEW_COUNT) - (OLD_COUNT)) / (NEW_COUNT)*100
);
```

How do I accomplish this in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

This should upsert statistics, adding new ones as you go.  It presumes a unique key on MODEL; if that's not true, then you'd have to do inserts as Angelina said, getting only the most recent row for a single MODEL entry.

```
MERGE INTO STATISTICS tgt
using (SELECT '&MY_MODEL' AS MODEL,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIENTS) AS NEW_COUNT,
              SYSDATE AS DATE_COUNT,
              NULL AS OLD_COUNT,
              NULL OLD_DATE,
              NULL AS PRCNT_CHANGE
         FROM DUAL) src
   on (TGT.MODEL = SRC.MODEL)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
     SET TGT.NEW_COUNT = SRC.NEW_COUNT,
         TGT.NEW_DATE  = SRC.NEW_DATE,
         TGT.OLD_COUNT = TGT.NEW_COUNT,
         TGT.OLD_DATE  = TGT.NEW_DATE,
         TGT.PRCNT_CHG = 100 * (SRC.NEW_COUNT - TGT.NEW_COUNT) / (SRC.NEW_COUNT)
            -- NEEDS DIV0/NULL CHECKING
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT
    (MODEL, NEW_COUNT, NEWDATE, OLD_COUNT, OLD_DATE, PRCNT_CHANGE)
  VALUES
    (src.MODEL, src.NEW_COUNT, src.NEWDATE, src.OLD_COUNT, src.OLD_DATE, src.PRCNT_CHANGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO STATISTICS(MODEL,NEW_COUNT,NEW_DATE,OLD_COUNT,OLD_DATE,PRNCT_CHANGE)
SELECT MODEL, 
       (  SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM TABLE(USERS)
       ),
       SYSDATE,
       NEW_COUNT,
       NEW_DATE,
       (((NEW_COUNT) - (OLD_COUNT)) / (NEW_COUNT)*100)
FROM SEMANTIC.COUNT_STATISTICS
WHERE MODEL = '&MY_MODEL'
AND trunc(NEW_DATE) = trunc(NEW_DATE -1)
;
```